# Nature of Spin in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, quantum-spin, representation-theory

If the orbital angular momentum of an electron in an atomic orbital is associated with (generated by) an asymmetry in the orbital wave function, is it also the case that the intrinsic spin of a free electron (as one specific example) in QFT is associated with an asymmetry in the coherent excitation pattern of the electron matter field/EM field constituting the electron? Or, is intrinsic spin more fundamental, perhaps relating to the fact that the underlying matter field is a spinor field.

Comment: What do you mean by "an asymmetry in the coherent excitation pattern of the electron matter field/EM field constituting the electron"?

Comment: For example, the two conjugate phased nodes of an individual p-orbital.

Answer (score 2):

No, the intrinsic spin of a particle is just a consequence of a "particle" being represented by an irreducible representation of the the Poincaré group.

The spin of the particle is determined by the dimension of the representation that it assumes under the double covering group $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ of the Lorentz group $SO(1,3)$. For example, spin 1/2 particles live in the fundamental (or spin-1/2) representation of $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$. These come in either left handed reps (1/2,0) or in right handed reps (0,1/2), both of which are spin 1/2 representations.

Comment: There's a bit of terminological confusion in this answer: The *unitary* representations of the Poincaré group are all infinite-dimensional and not the finite-dimensional representations denoted by a pair of half-integers $(s_1,s_2)$ you talk about later.

Comment: In what sense exactly are those reps infinite dimensional? My understanding was that a chiral spinor lives in a two dimensional complex space. Or are you saying that is the case, but that’s not a unitary representation of the PG?

Comment: The latter. A chiral spinor *field* lives in two dimensions, its *particle states* live in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. It is the *latter* space upon which a *unitary* representation exists.

Comment: I see.. but then how can we say that the (1/2,0) spinor is an irrep of the PG if it’s only dimension 2, or is that wrong too?

Comment: It is irreducible. It is just not unitary, and it doesn't have to be - only the quantum space of states needs a unitary rep.

Comment: I think I see.. So the Poincare group is made up of these finite dimensional irreps, but it itself is infinite dimensional (unitary) representation, is what I'm gathering

Comment: Can you please translate from the formal mathematics (which I am not able to follow) to the conceptual basis?

Comment: @CSnowden If you are leaning QFT, learning this terminology is necessary for a complete understanding.. I take it you are at least almost graduated or are in grad school.. If not, then considering QFT to understand spin is probably not the best idea

Comment: I'll try to rephrase my question.  Is the symmetry expressed by the group SL(2,C) a property of the specific wave function of the electron matter field (in Hilbert space) - in that sense the answer to my original, broad question would be that intrinsic spin is more a property of the excitation of the electron matter field, but more highly structured than my original basic statement about being asymmetric.